# Object-c How to call father method in father when being subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, subclass

```
@interface Father : NSObject
-(void)show;
@end

@interface Child : Father
-(void)show;
@end
- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  [self show];
  return self;
}

- (void)show
{
  NSLog(@"I am father");
}
@end

@implementation Child

- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  [self show];
  return self;
}

- (void)show
{
  NSLog(@"I am child");
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  Child *child = [[Child alloc] init];
}

Output: 
I am child
I am child
```

From the code and output, we can see [self show] in father actually call [child show]. Is there a way to call father method in father when the method is overridden by child, In other words, Is there a way to choose to father method or child method.

Comment: call in chile class [super show]; it will run father class method.

Comment: Hint: `super`. Why are you calling [super init]` ??? Answer is there.

Comment: @MidhunMP, I think, the OP means that he wants to call the base class implementation **from the base class**, even if child overrode it.

Comment: @MidhunMP, yes, it's a weird thing to ask for, especially in the context of Objective-C (I'm not sure if it's even possible). It's like "overriding" a non-virtual function in C++ (when you don't really override it, but just hide the parent's implementation), when parent calls his own implementation, whereas a child calls it's own.

Comment: @MidhunMP, `self` will call a child's implementation, if child overrides it. If I understand it correctly, the OP wants the parent's implementation to be called, when he calls it from within the parent's code, no matter what.

Comment: @FreeNickname: Ohh!!! I don't think there is a way to do that. Instead of calling the parent method from child.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation Child

- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  [self show];
  return self;
}

- (void)show
{
  NSLog(@"I am child");
  [super show];  // This line call show method of father class
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  Child *child = [[Child alloc] init];
}
```

Try above code.

Go through Objective-C doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can Call Super class methods using

```
[super show]; //call this method from within child class
```

This method execution, calls the `show` method in `Super Class`(Father Class In our Case)

Hope this helps